# Protractor -Date Picker wheel in Android, not able to automate

Tags: android, angularjs, datepicker, protractor, appium

I am using protractor to automate the android hybrid app using Protractor and appium.
I am not able to automate the Date Picker wheel. It is not able to recognize the date picker element itself.  Kindly suggests:

DO we need to first to switch to Native App mode, as i am using autowebview = true. Kindly Advise and how to switch to Native mode.

I tried using the code, but fails to recognize the date picker:

1>>>

```
var date = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.DatePicker//android.widget.LinearLayout[0]/EditText")); date.click(); date.clear();
date.sendKeys("Apr");
```

Gets error and unable to find xpath.

2>> `List date = browser.element(by.className("android.widget.DatePicker"));` Gets error Invalid left hand side assignments

3>>

```
browser.switchTo().frame('android.widget.DatePicker');
var day1=browser.findElement(By.className("android.widget.DatePicker"));
findElement(By.id("android:id/day")); day1.clear(); day1.sendKeys('05');
```

[image: Date Picker Wheel in Android]